# How to: collapsible two tier org chart creation using CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, treeview

Expectation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViEPM.jpg

> I tried using treant JS library but take a look at this link here 
>   http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/custom-colored/
>
> Tell me where/how the configuration (users and titles) information is
>   passed. The html gets rendered with it but still can't figure out
>   where input is passed. Must have missed something from documentation.
>   I see that Github response for this is not super active.
>
> I see jQuery horizontal tree but that's not free. womp womp.
>
> Open to other ideas too. I wonder if this is possible with css
>   show/hide type style almost like navigation.

**UPDATE[11/29]..**
As of now, I am trying to tackle this as a CSS+jQuery solution. Progress: http://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/ptpyp66L/6/

How do I approach the show/hide to control parent-child level display. By default, I'd like to expand all levels and show with the option to click on each level that has children.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card" id="cardOne">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="img-circle">
      </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <p><b>Abe</b></p>
                <p>SR DIRECTOR BUSINESS PLANNING</p>
                </div>              
            </div>        
    <div class="row">
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a id="menu-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>        
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card" id="cardTwo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="img-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <p><b>Adam</b></p>
                <p>DIRECTOR BUSINESS PLANNING</p>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card" id="cardThree">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="img-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <p><b>Anthony</b></p>
                <p>RAD BUSINESS PLANNER</p>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For hierarchical Org Chart, I'm using this one, it's easy to use and you can add as many details you want such as job title, job description and images, All you have to do is provide json data,

https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart - source

here is a working sample

https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/ajax-datasource.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      $.mockjax({
        url: '/orgchart/initdata',
        responseTime: 1000,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        responseText: {
          'name': 'Lao Lao',
          'title': 'general manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
                { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
                  'children': [
                    { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                    { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Li', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Wei', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Tie', 'title': 'department manager' }
          ]
        }
      });

      $('#chart-container').orgchart({
        'data' : '/orgchart/initdata',
        'depth': 2,
        'nodeContent': 'title'
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this. What was your experience with changing the HTML layout of each card for this? I'll have to do that to meet my objective from this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for answer for the Treant JS plugin question I originally had, I found out that each sample folder has a .js file that contains the JSON object with configuration. That said I intend to try the CSS+jQuery method. For any question about that, I'll open a new thread.